# M1 Macbook Pro is lagging a lot on minimal usage

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, apple-silicon

I use an entry-level M1 MacBrook pro 8GB for tasks that majorly use Chrome, Excel and a couple of other light video and photo editing tools like Canva. But it seems that my mac starts lagging and starts giving delayed responses to trackpad clicks, movements and keyboard typing. I can actually see frames appear when switching desktop screens and between apps. And this issue seems to top when I have 3-4 desktop screens open which is very basic and not so power-hungry tasks. Can't seem to figure what the issue is when I have seen people having more that 10 desktop screens with more that 50 tabs opened simultaneously working like a breeze on the same configured machine. Attaching the Activity monitor snapshot below. Can someone please help with this?

[Apps consuming highest memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5wIy.png)
[image: Memory Pressure and RAM usage]

Comment: WhatsApp looks a little ridiculous. If you close its browser window, what happens? Maybe you have WhatsApp running in several browsers in the different desktop screens you have running. Worth a look.

Comment: Chrome is using more RAM than you have.

Comment: You don't want to use Chrome on a Mac with 8Gb RAM.

Comment: Chrome is horrible on Mac for many reasons. Avoid it at all costs. (I know two others have commented on Chrome but it's really worth saying a third time: Chrome is awful.)